Why there is a change in behavior of qcut function in pandas 2.2.1
The following code produces different results in pandas 2.1.4 and 2.2.2 (also tested with 2.2.1 -same results)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 182), columns=['val'])
pd.qcut(df.val, 10, labels=False).value_counts()

2.1.4 output:
val
0    19
1    18
2    18
3    18
4    18
5    18
6    18
7    18
8    18
9    18
Name: count, dtype: int64

2.2.2 output:
val
0    19
7    19
1    18
2    18
3    18
4    18
5    18
8    18
9    18
6    17
Name: count, dtype: int64

I do not expect three different counts of items in different bins (17, 18, 19) as 2.2.2 would calculate.

maybe you have to ask authors of pandas. Or you have to read documentation for qcut. Maybe they decided to change code for this function. OR maybe it it bug in code and you should send this information to authors of pandas.

Examination of the source code shows that the qcut code changed between 2.1.4 and 2.2.2 as evidenced by your finding. I can't find any explanation reported. You might want to report this issue using link

Reported: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/58240
